# Window manager not working

Tags: upgrade, lightdm, kdm

When upgrading Kubuntu from 12.04 to 12.10 I agreed to stop the kdm daemon and now I can't get any window manager to initialize. I do however still have my Burg boot screen. So now how do I finish my install via shell scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

you can start manually . If you a login screen then press keys of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd> . then login there with username & password .

Now type this

```
sudo start kdm
```

give the sudo password .

hope that helps .